# Selection sort in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

Is following C code is written according to selection sort algorithm? I'm little bit confused about it. However, it gives correct results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n], i = 0, j, min;
    while (i < n) {
        printf("Enter no. %d:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i, min = a[i]; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] < min)
                min = a[j];
            else
                continue;
            a[j] = a[i];
            a[i] = min;   
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At a very quick glance, seems about correct. However, I didn't have time to prove it is correct.

Comment: This is a BubbleSort.

Comment: In your question you should explain more about what you already know and what you don't know. Be specific, name those parts of the code that you are unsure about and why you are unsure. To be helpful we need to know more about your current understanding.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Selection Sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int array[100], n, c, d, position, swap;

  printf("Enter number of elements\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);

  for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++)
  {
    position = c;

    for (d = c + 1; d < n; d++)
    {
      if (array[position] > array[d])
        position = d;
    }
    if (position != c)
    {
      swap = array[c];
      array[c] = array[position];
      array[position] = swap;
    }
  }

  printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    printf("%d\n", array[c]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You answered with a bunch of code that is totally unrelated to the OP's code and you don't explain what the difference between these codes is.